# How to match a string with a space in the end to lines in a file using bash?

Tags: regex, string, bash

So, I am trying to match a string to some lines in a file. Now, the lines in the files are in the format:

```
peeyush (#$#@$)
peeyush-gupta ($%%&%)
```

Now, my problem is when I try to search 'peeyush', I should get only first line as the output. Till now, I have been doing this:

```
line='peeyush'
grep $line test.txt
```

Now, the search string would definitely come in a variable as this thing is going in loop. So, this gives me both the string as result. I want to match the string 'peeyush ' (with a space), while it's matching without spaces.

Comment: `grep "${line} " test.txt`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
line=peeyush
grep "$line " test.txt
```

Comment: Might want to add a `^` to the front too so that it doesn't match `something-else-peeyush`

Comment: Shit, I was using single quotes instead of double! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
line='^peeyush '
grep "$line" test.txt
```